# Prolog DCGs: Converting from programming notation to logical notation

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm trying to convert from this notation:

```
A and (B or C) equ A and B or A and C)
```

to standard logical notation i.e. things like `and(A,B), or(A,B), neg(A)...`

I thought that I nice way of doing it would be using DCGs (I made up this question because I want to practice DCGs).  Any ideas why my conversion isn't working?  So far I've just written the disjunction and the case when we get a variable.  The answer I want should be or(atom(X),atom(Y)).

```
convert1(atom(X)) --> [X], {var(X)},!.
convert1(or(X,Y)) --> convert1(X), [or], convert1(Y).

test_convert1( F ) :-
   phrase( convert1( F ), [X, or, Y] ).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error in `test_convert1/1`. It should read

```
test_convert1(F) :-
    phrase(convert1(F), [X, or, Y]).
```

Comment: Thanks larsman, argh so silly.  This hasn't fixed my issue though.  I just made a copy/paste error when putting the code onto here.  Thanks though.

Comment: @imperial, then which part is not working? I get the output `X = or(atom(_G443), atom(_G449))`, which is exactly what I'd expect. If you wanted to see `X` and `Y` in the output, don't use `var/1`.

Comment: Really :S!  How do you call it?  I wanted to call test_convert1(F) and for it to output what you've said..  Hmmmm sorry I'm probably doing something really silly.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you need Prolog variables in your terms for further processing, your code is fine. If you want pretty display, use `convert1(atom(X)) --> [X], {atom(X)}, !.` and `x`, `y` instead of `X`, `Y`.

Comment: Hmm, what I meant was if I can `test_convert(F).` then I get the answer false.  I don't get any output of the logical expression.  If you're getting the answer you must be calling it differently to me then?  Thank you for all you help :).

Comment: If I run `test_convert(F)`, I get an autocorrection prompt asking whether I meant `test_convert1(F)`, which gives the expected output (SWI-Prolog 5.6.9).

Answer (score 1):

Your code includes two mistakes:

1. In the first clause you're not reading `X` from the parsed list.
2. Cuts in DCG's should be outside of the curly braces.

A working version is:

```
convert1(atom(X)) --> [X], {var(X)}, !.
convert1(or(X,Y)) --> convert1(X), [or], convert1(Y).
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out the errors.  There are still no answers coming out for some reason.  Would you mind having a look?  I think it's probably in the test_convert/1 ?